# App Fabric: Method not found: 'System.String Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Utility.GetInstallPathFromRegistry()'

Tags: windows, caching, appfabric

I am attempting to install App fabric on a Windows Server 2008 R2 VM.

Here are the steps taken:

- Created file share accessible to Network Service
- Ran WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe
  - Disable Automatic Microsoft Updates
  - Installed:
    - Caching Services
    - Cache Client
    - Cache Administration
  - Checked “Set Caching Service Configuration”
  - Selected XML Provider
  - Set file share
  - Use default ports
- Installed Hotfix AppFabric1.1-RTM-KB2716015-x64-ENU.exe
- Rebooted Server
- Started AppFabric Caching Service

But when I run the 'App Fabric Caching Administration PS' as Administrator I get the following error:

```
Connect-AFCacheClusterConfiguration : Method not found: 'System.String Microsof
t.ApplicationServer.Caching.Utility.GetInstallPathFromRegistry()'.
At line:1 char:100
+ Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned Process;Import-Module DistributedCacheAdministr
ation;Use-CacheCluster <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-AFCacheClusterConfigu
   ration], MissingMethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.MissingMethodException,Microsoft.Applicat
   ionServer.Caching.Commands.ConnectAFCacheClusterConfigurationCommand

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Any suggestions what the issue may be?

Comment: Not sure why this isn't getting more views, and there's precious little on Bing/Google about this error. Maybe no one is using appfabric.

Comment: AppFabric is going out of support. If you have a choice, use something else. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appfabric/2015/04/02/microsoft-appfabric-1-1-for-windows-server-ends-support-422016/

Comment: That is the dream.

Comment: Incidentally, I found the reason that I was getting this error message. It seems to indicate early failure. If you are simply missing the appFabric installation altogether, this will likely be the first error message you will see. I don't know if it helps the issue in the question, so I'm just leaving this as a comment.